# Odd property declaration syntax containing angular brackets <>

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just downloaded FourInARow from 2015 WWDC sample code (https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/) and noticed an odd property declaration in file `AAPLViewController.m`

```
@property NSArray<NSMutableArray<CAShapeLayer *> *> *chipLayers;
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a new addition to Objective-C, called [Lightweight Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID173). It was introduced in iOS9 / OS X 10.11 in order to enhance interoperability between Swift and Objective-C. As the documentation says:

> Objective-C declarations of NSArray, NSSet and NSDictionary types
>   using lightweight generic parameterization are imported by Swift with
>   information about the type of their contents preserved.
>
> For example, consider the following Objective-C property declarations:

```
@property NSArray<NSDate *>* dates; 
@property NSSet<NSString *>* words; 
@property NSDictionary<KeyType: NSURL *, NSData *>* cachedData;
```

> Here’s how Swift imports them:

```
var dates: [NSDate]
var words: Set<String> 
var cachedData: [NSURL: NSData]
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Michał Ciuba's answer:

Despite that the documentation ([Lightweight Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID173)) doesn't seem to explicitly mention it, it's not just for Swift: this syntax does affect Objective-C. If you declare, say, a mutable array of `CAShapeLayer*`, then adding or accessing incompatible elements will produce compiler warnings. E.g.

```
NSMutableArray<CAShapeLayer*>* array = [NSMutableArray new];
[array addObject:[CATextLayer new]]; // warning
CATextLayer* layer = array[0]; // warning
CALayer* layer = array[0]; // OK, because CALayer is a superclass of CAShapeLayer
```

Comment: How can a superclass conform to its subclass? Don't you mean vice versa?

Comment: @asma22 that's exactly the case when the compiler will issue a warning, because it is wrong.

Comment: But you are accepting `CALayer` which is the superclass of `CAShapeLayer` it Doesn't have all of what a `CAShapeLayer` object has. `CAShapeLayer` is subclass which is to be conformed to. In your comment you said *OK, because CALayer is a superclass of CAShapeLayer*. Which should have been something like . *OK, because CALayer is a **subclass** of CAShapeLayer*

Comment: @asma22 the last line is OK because: all you can see through the variable `layer` is `CALayer`'s methods, correct? Now if you assign to `layer` something that's more than that, but at least has `CALayer` methods, then code that works with this variable `layer` should be fine.